# Display data from 3 tables Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am trying display data from 3 tables like this ->

course name | test name | question count

---

course name1 | test name1 | 3

I have relation between Test and Question 1:N

**Test.php**

```
public $table = 'Test';

protected $fillable = [
    'name',
];

public function question()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Question');
}
```

**Question.php**

```
public $table = 'Question';

public function test()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Test');
}
```

**TestController.php**

```
public function courses(Subject $subject) {
    $subject_with_courses = Subject::with(['course'])->where('id', 

    $subject['id'])->first();

    $courses = Course::with(['test'])->get();
    $questions = $courses->question;

    return view('admin.test.list_course', [
        'courses' => $courses,
        'questions' => $questions,
        'subject' => $subject
    ]);
}
```

**list_course.php**

```
@foreach($courses as $course)
    <tr>
        <td>
            {{ $course->name }}
        </td>
        <td>
            @foreach($course->test as $test)
                {{ $test->name }}
            @endforeach
        </td>
        <td>
            @foreach($course->questions as $test)
                {{ $test->count() }}
            @endforeach
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

I get error "Property [question] does not exist on this collection instance."

Can anybody help me with this, please ?
Thank you!!

Comment: what does your test and question table look like?

Answer (score 0):

This is what is giving you the error:

TestController.php:

```
$courses = Course::with(['test'])->get();
$questions = $courses->question; // <---- $courses is a Collection not a Model
```

You are trying to access the questions property of the Model, but `$courses` is a Collection of Models.

Comment: I'm not sure which questions you are looking for, but you need to get the questions from a single Course. So something like `$courses->first()->questions` would get the questions from the first Course ... assuming you've got a `questions` relation on your Course model.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access Course model property but `$courses` is collection of `Course`

Answer (score 0):

You can [eager load](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) the questions in your controller:

```
$courses = Course::with(['test', 'test.question'])->get();
```

The questions belong to the test and not the Course, so you cant call `$course->question` on the Course Model.

In your View:

```
@foreach($courses as $course)
    <tr>
        <td>
            {{ $course->name }}
        </td>

        <td>
            @foreach($course->test as $test)
                {{ $test->name }}
            @endforeach
        </td>

        <td>
            @foreach($course->test as $test)
                {{ $test->question->count() }}
            @endforeach
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```